# select table, check and prompt when value match

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have my table named sup_mon:

```
genmat_id    mat_name  Stock_balance
1            bar           50
5            steel         10
20           bolt          5
```

HTML:

```
        <?php 
        $resource2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM genmaterial WHERE mat_name='$mat' AND size='$unit' ORDER BY genmat_id DESC limit 0,1",$con);

        while($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($resource2))
            { 

            ?>
        <form name="stockout" method="post" action="stock_out.php">
                <label><b>Material</b></label>
                <input  maxlength="25" type="text" readonly name="material" id="material" required="required" style="height:20px"  value="<?php echo $rows['mat_name']; ?>" >

            <input type="number" name="stock_out"/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    <?php };?>
```

How can I check first stock_balance from the sup_mon table  for the material in the material text box from the html? and prompt reorder message when `stock_balance` of that particular material is less than 10?

Comment: Use echo if the conditional statement is TRUE or use JS.

Comment: if you provide your php & html code we can help you.

Comment: okay.. ill update it.

Comment: already updated my post sir.. pls help. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a second query inside the loop to check if stock_balance is less than 10 like this:

```
<?php 
    $resource2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM genmaterial WHERE mat_name='$mat' AND size='$unit' ORDER BY genmat_id DESC limit 0,1",$con);

    while($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($resource2))
        { 
            $resource3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sup_mon WHERE genmat_id = '" . $rows2['genmat_id'] . "'",$con);
            $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($resource3);
            if($row3['Stock_balance'] < 10)
            {
                echo "Stock balance is less then 10 please reorder";
                header("refresh: 5; order.php");
            }
        ?>
    <form name="stockout" method="post" action="stock_out.php">
            <label><b>Material</b></label>
            <input  maxlength="25" type="text" readonly name="material" id="material" required="required" style="height:20px"  value="<?php echo $rows['mat_name']; ?>" >

        <input type="number" name="stock_out"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: Does this prompt only on submit sir?

Comment: no this will prompt once the page is loaded. if you need to do that once the user submits the form, you'd need ajax and javascript. do you need to check the value of text box material with the database Stock_balance value dynamically (i.e. once the user changes and/or submits it)? if yes why do you have readonly attribute in your textbox?

Comment: What if you added a `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` above `if($row3['Stock_balance'] < 10)` or something similar? That way it will fire up when hitting the submit button.

Comment: @VOLKAN the mat_name is readonly sir because I only get the id from previous link array of materials.

Comment: it is also good that it will only prompt upon page load.
Can you add redirection to page sir to order.php after the prompt?

Comment: added header to redirect to order.php after 5 seconds. hope it helps.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.